# Grouping by generic parameter in Slick

Tags: scala, generics, slick

I am trying to implement generic grouping using Slick 3.2.3. By generic grouping I mean grouping the same query by different parameters or sets thereof.

Supposing I have a table:

```
class MyTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[MyEntry](tag, "my_table") {
  def text1 = column[String]("text1")
  def text2 = column[Option[String]]("text2")
  def list = column[List[String]]("list")   //  I am using postgres+slick_pg
  ...
}
```

Then I have a complex query with several joins and I would like to be able to group it by *text1*, (*text1*, *text2*), *list* etc. One way to do it would be to define a generic function which performs grouping using *extractor* parameter:

```
private def getData[T](extractor: MyTable => T) = {
  //    supposing MyTable comes second in the list
  //    of joined tables in my complex query
  val groupedQuery = myComplexQuery.groupedBy(x => extractor(x._2))
  ...
  //    here goes aggregation functions, mapping etc.
}
```

where one of *extractor* implementations may be defined as

```
val extractor: MyTable => (Rep[String], Rep[Option[String]]) = me => me.text1 -> me.text2
```

However, since *extractor* is generic, *groupBy* cannot find matching Shape for T type, and it means that I will have to provide it as well. My question is how exactly to define such Shapes? Documentation for slick.lifted package lacks examples, and it is not exactly obvious what generic types K, T, G and P mean in Query#groupBy definition (or FlatShapeLevel for that matter). I would appreciate if somebody provided examples of such extractor functions at least for a primitive type (String) and a tuple2 (say, (String, Option[String])). Or perhaps there is a better way to achieve the same result which I have overlooked? Thanks.